# How to read full bytes using port basestream

Tags: c#, serial-port, task-parallel-library

I am working on serial port communication. While using `BaseStream` I am writing and reading the port.

```
port.BaseStream.Write(dataItems, 0, dataItems.Length);
int receivedBytes = port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
Thread.Sleep(100);
var receiveData = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
```

Hereafter write, I am sleeping the thread so that I will get full bytes. Is there any other way around that I can wait that all bytes are available?

**Note**

The last byte should be `22`. Also the above code is running in `Task` named as `public async Task PortHitmethod(Iterations iterations)`

Comment: The Read method is blocking until you get the number of bytes in buffer.Length.  If you are transmitting binary data when sending data at the beginning of the message so on the receive end you know how many byes are in the message.

Comment: What do you mean by *"full bytes"*?  You cannot read partial bytes.  Are you referring to a complete message or datagram?  BTW your program does not actually *"read the port"* directly.  It merely fetches data from a system buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a wrong way to use `Stream.Read`.  The correct pattern is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netcore-3.1):

```
    Stream s = new MemoryStream();
    ...
    // Now read s into a byte buffer with a little padding.
    byte[] bytes = new byte[s.Length + 10];
    int numBytesToRead = (int)s.Length;
    int numBytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
        // Read may return anything from 0 to 10.
        int n = s.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, 10);
        numBytesRead += n;
        numBytesToRead -= n;
    } while (numBytesToRead > 0);
    s.Close();
```

P.S.  If you think you should use `Thread.Sleep` then you can be sure you are certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: why padding is neccessary ?

Comment: It is not, actually.  In real life, I've never needed to use it.